# set a dynamic range from visible cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code in which I am trying to sort the data set in a csv file based on the content of a cell in another (the main) workbook.  Then based on this sort, copy a range of visible cells between the first and sixth columns, but with a dynamic last row thus the range will be dynamic.  This dynamic range is then pasted into the main sheet, which will then allow me to do further work on this dataset.

Can't seem to get the sort to work or the dynamic range working.  I've tried all sorts of variation on the code below and am looking for some inspiration.

```
Sub Get_OA_Data()

'Find OA data from source SQL file and copy into serial number generator 
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wkb2 As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

'This section sets the workbooks and worksheets to be used for this macro
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Entry")
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("\\srvabdotfpr08\PC_APPS\forum\Gateshead Serialisation\sys_serialisation1.csv")
Set ws2 = wkb2.Worksheets("sys_serialisation1")
Set rng2 = ws.Range("F6")

'   This line deletes any content of the cannot assign serial number added previously
ws.Range("I6:I7").ClearContents

'This hides all rows which do not match the desired OA number (found in rng2)
For Each Cell In ws2.Range("A1").End(xlDown)
    If Left(Cell.Value, 6) <> rng2.Value Then
        Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next Cell

Set StartCell = ws2.Range("A1")
LastRow = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
LastColumn = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Column

'This section selects and copies the visible range from csv file into serialisation generator
Set rng = ws2.Range(StartCell.ws2.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
    rng.Copy
    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("D12").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial 'Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False     

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've bought a couple of books, but none of the stuff in my books is helping with this issue.

P.S  I have used very similar code with specific set ranges and it works fine, but this one has me stumped.  There may also be an issue with the dataset- which is why I have the LEFT formula in the code (but this seems to work OK).

Comment: Not your problem but, `rng.Copy` and then you only need`ws.Range("D12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` . You do not need the two steps you have inbetween

Comment: You need to copy the `SecialCells`xlCellTypeVisible. - See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells)

Comment: Udearboy, thanks, I was having problems with the shortcut code, but I suspect it was syntax.  and the copy special cells bit - thanks also.  another one for me to store in my brain as I learn how to do this stuff (very slowly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Get_OA_Data()

Dim wkb2 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, xCell As Range
Dim LR As Long, LC As Long, LR2 As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Entry")
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("\\srvabdotfpr08\PC_APPS\forum\Gateshead Serialisation\sys_serialisation1.csv")
Set ws2 = wkb2.Worksheets("sys_serialisation1")

ws.Range("I6:I7").ClearContents
LR2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each xCell In ws2.Range("A1:A" & LR2)
    xCell.EntireRow.Hidden = Left(xCell.Value, 6) <> ws.Range("F6")
Next xCell

LR = ws2.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LC = ws2.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set rng = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, 1), ws2.Cells(LR, LC))
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    ws2.Range("D12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: This one worked to a degree - think I may have the wrong destination as the dynamic range pastes back into the source sheet.  But this is easily fixed.  Thanks for the help, I will have a look at your method in detail, try and find it in the few books I have and keep on learning.